# Guava: Is it valid to cast a Multimap to generic supertypes?

Tags: java, generics, casting, guava, multimap

Currently I'm implementing the Multimap class to allow duplicates using Multisets. In particular, I am working on the `boolean putAll(Multimap<? extends K, ? extends V> multimap)` method.

I want to do this:

```
Map<K, Collection<V>> map = ((Multimap<K, V>)multimap).asMap();
```

where `asMap()` would normally return a `Map<? extends K, Collection<? extends V>>`.

Is this valid (won't throw errors provided I don't add to the map)? If not, how can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The argument for `putAll` is used in a read-only way, so `? extends` is what you want.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I want to acquire the `asMap()` object from it. However, I'm concerned that when I call this method and try to get a `Map<K, Collection<V>>` this method will throw a ClassCastException. I don't know too much about it though and my brain's burned a little.

Comment: You won't get a `ClassCastException` because the types are erased. You can just do `Map<? extends K, Collection<? extends V>> map = multimap.asMap();`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington The HashMap method `putAll` accepts a `Map<K, Collection<V>>` though.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. I suggest you include the full cods for your method in the question.

Comment: @PaulBoddington That single line is pretty much it. I'm putting this Map into a HashMap<K, Collection<V>> putAll method. The putAll method only accepts a Map<K, Collection<V>> though.

Comment: That single line cannot possibly throw a `ClassCastException`. However it may cause a `ClassCastException` later on in some circumstances, depending on where `multimap` came from. More context is required to answer this properly.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I'm implementing `Multimap` so it technically can come from anywhere. I'm calling `map.putAll(((Multimap<K, V>)multimap).asMap());` I want to make sure I don't get an error from this.

Comment: @aspaltv: The `putAll` method on `Map` accepts `Map<? extends K, ? extends V>`... you shouldn't need to cast at all.

Comment: @ColinD You're right. The problem is that a Map<K, Collection<V>> accepts a Map<? extends K, ? extends Collection<V>> (not Collection<? extends V>).

Comment: Ah, right. Actually, if you're trying to store the contents of the `Multimap` that's passed into `putAll(Multimap)`, you should _not_ use `Map.putAll`. Why? Because the `Collection` values in the `asMap()` view of the `Multimap` are _views_ and will change when that `Multimap` changes. `Multimap.putAll` is supposed to store the actual keys and values. If you have a multimap `A` and another multimap `B` and call `A.putAll(B)`, a change to `B` made after that should not have any effect on `A`. The way you're doing it, it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not valid, for the same reason that it is not valid to cast a `List<T>` to `List<Object>`.

`Multimap.asMap()` returns a view, [according to the documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#asMap()). This means that

```
Multimap<K, V> multimap = ...;
Map<SuperOfK, SuperOfV> map = (<some cast>) multimap.asMap();
map.put(superOfK, superOfV);
```

Should update the multimap. Whilst this wouldn't itself result in a `ClassCastException`, doing something like iterating the keys would:

```
for (K key : multimap.keys()) { }
```

Hence, it is not type safe to cast like that, so it is forbidden.

Of course, you don't have this problem if your multimap is immutable - but it is in general the reason why you shouldn't. And saying "I won't add to the map" isn't good enough for the compiler - it doesn't know that you won't.

Comment: I'm not planning on updating the Multimap. Is there a valid way to get the Map<K, Collection<V>> object from it.

Comment: "I'm not planning on updating" the compiler doesn't know that. The only way is to explicitly copy the data into a new data structure of the correct type.

Comment: Alright, I got it. I'll just make an anonymous class that is a view of that Multimap. Thanks for the assist, brother!

Comment: @aspaltv You can use [`Collections.unmodifiableMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-) to get a view and fix the generics all in one go!

Comment: @TavianBarnes  `((Multimap<K, V>)multimap).asMap()` is what's causing the problem. `Collections.unmodifiableMap(multimap.asMap())` would return a Map<K, Collection<? extends V>> when I need a Map<K, Collection<V>>

Comment: Ahhh right.  What would work would be [`Multimaps.unmodifiableMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#unmodifiableMultimap(com.google.common.collect.Multimap)) except it has the wrong generics

Comment: @aspaltv but you can call `Collections.<K, V>unmodifiableMap(multimap.asMap())`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes You should add this as a new answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner That doesn't work. `Collections.<K, Collection<V>>unmodifiableMap()` accepts a Map<? extends K, ? extends Collection<V>>, but `asMap()` returns a Map<? extends K, Collection<? extends V>>.

Answer (score 2):

Others have covered your specific question, but I think that you're asking the wrong question (and trying to do something you shouldn't).

First, I'd want to ask why you're implementing `Multimap` yourself. It seems likely that you could avoid doing that.

Second, you're trying to use `map.putAll(Map)` to add the `asMap()` view of the `Multimap` passed in to your `Multimap.putAll(Multimap)` implementation. This is almost certainly wrong and would violate the specification of `Multimap.putAll`. The `Collection` values in the `asMap()` view are each live views of the values for the associated key and their contents will *change* when that multimap changes. If you add those collections directly to the `Map` you presumably have backing your `Multimap` implementation, your `Multimap` will end up changing if the other `Multimap` is modified afterwards. Not only that, but what happens if you already have values for that key in your `Map`?